# Phrase similarity from List

Tags: python, list, dataframe, similarity, difflib

Hi assuming I have 2 lists:

```
names = ['Daniel', 'Mario', 'Mandy', 'Jolene', 'Fabio']
places = ['on top of the table', 'France', 'valley of the kings']
```

and a dataframe with some sentences
ex:

DataframeOrig

```
Index | Sent
0     | Mandy went to France on the Eiffel Tower
1     | Daniele was dancing on top of the box
2     | I am eating on top of the table
3     | Maria went to the valley of the kings
```

I would like to use a distance metric like difflib to scan the sentences and compare phrases to the list having a determined offset. Hopefully the result of this would be:

```
Index | Sent                                     | Result
0     | Mandy went to France on the Eiffel Tower | Mandy
1     | Daniele was dancing on top of the box    | Daniel
2     | I am eating on top of the table          | on top of the table
3     | Maria went to the valley of the kings    | Mario, valley of the kings
```

How would you go about it without using loads of loops to get phrase matches?

Comment: Why can't you just loop over the dataframe column, and use **in** keyword to find the phrases? Example: `for row in df: for phrase in your_list: if phrase in row: result.append(phrase)`. Later you can make a column out of it. `df['result']`= result

Comment: Because I don't want to find exact matches ex: I want to catch Daniele even if in the list it is Daniel

Comment: Daniele will also be scanned using my above said code and get matched with Daniel. It won't be found out if you use **'Daniel '** with a space after.

Comment: What about instances ex: Georgi and Georgus?

Comment: To which phrase you want to compare them with?

Comment: For example I would have a sentence: 'Georgus is out of town' and Georgi is in the list

Comment: You may use nltk, a module in python for NLP which gives you multiple functions to perform such task.

Comment: To which function are you referring too?

Comment: It's called stemming. https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.stem.html